# Play framework with angular2

Tags: playframework, npm, gulp, angular

I'm working on personal learning project and I want to use angular2 with play framework but i've been facing some issues for more then a week now.

I've been trying to set up angular2 but i cannot make it to work.

I've tried to implement example from angular2 web page but it didn't work eihter.

Here is my working repository:https://github.com/viniolli/borrow-a-book

Basic requiremant are: scala 2.11.7, npm and gulp.

If you want me to paste certain files, please tell it(i gonna paste just more important ones).

If you have any advise, or external article, feel free to post it.

*app/views/main.scala.html*

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/materialize.css")'>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")'>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/es6-shim.js")'></script>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/angular2-polyfills.js")'></script>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/es6-module-loader.js")'></script>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/typescript.js")'></script>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/require.js")'></script>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/angular2.dev.js")'></script>
        <script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/lib/system.js")'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
          System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: {'assets/javascripts': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
          });
          System.import('assets/javascripts/app/components/first')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
        <my-app></my-app>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

*public/javascripts/app/components/first.ts*

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>"
})
export default class AppComponent { }

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.1",
    "materialize-css": "0.97.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

*gulpfile.js*

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');


// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del('dist/**/*');
});

gulp.task('libs-js', function () {
    return gulp.src([
          "node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js",
          "node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js",
          "node_modules/angular2/core.js",
          "node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.js",
          "node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js",
          "node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js",
          "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js",
          "node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js",
          "node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js",
          "node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js",
          "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js",
          "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
        ])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts/lib'));
});

gulp.task('libs-css', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/stylesheets"));
});
```

conf.routes

```
GET     /                               controllers.Application.index
GET     /materialize                    controllers.Application.materializeDemo
GET     /registration.html              controllers.Application.registrationGet

GET     /assets/*file                   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

After starting an app I have some problems:

404 - loading http://localhost:9000/angular2/core

404 - loading http://localhost:9000/angular2/platform/browser

and Uncaught TypeError: System.register is not a function(Js console)

Comment: A usual way to get started is to find an activator template for you frameworks. Have you seen https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-angular2-typescript ? Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are quite a few people, including me, looking into working with Angular2 + Play. Below links helped me get up and running.

Have a look at this template from Lightbend (formerly Typesafe) : 
lightbend [post](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-angular2-typescript), [github](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript#master)

This is the heroes example app in the angular tutorial integrated with play framework : lightbend [blog post](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/getting-started-with-angular-2), [github](https://github.com/vchu-vr/angular2_play)